# Why is chaining labels in the switch syntax allowed and what does it do?

Tags: java, syntax, switch-statement

I recently discovered, that in a java switch statement, multiple labels can be chained, but for no apparent effect. And it even allows labels that do not exist. For example you can do this:
`case ENUM_VALUE_1:ENUM_VALUE_2:`, or even this `case ENUM_VALUE_1:foobar:barfoo:`. As long as it ends with a colon, any value seems to be accepted.
First I though this might be a different way of grouping multiple cases, but that does not seem to be working. So I ran the following test

```
public class Main {

public enum TestEnum {
    A,
    B
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    TestEnum testEnum = TestEnum.B;

    switch (testEnum) {
        case A: System.out.println("Test 1: Case 1"); break;
        case B: System.out.println("Test 1: Case 2"); break;
    }

    switch (testEnum) {
        case A: System.out.println("Test 2: Case 1"); break;
        case B:A: System.out.println("Test 2: Case 2"); break; // Label A is already used in enum
    }

    switch (testEnum) {
        case A:B: System.out.println("Test 3: Case 1"); break; // Label B is already used in enum
        case B: System.out.println("Test 3: Case 2"); break;
    }

    switch (testEnum) {
        case A:BARFOO: System.out.println("Test 4: Case 1"); break; // Label BARFOO does not exist
        case B:FOOBAR: System.out.println("Test 4: Case 2"); break; // Label FOOBAR does not exist
    }

    switch (testEnum) {
        case A:B: System.out.println("Test 5: Case 1"); break;
    }
}}
```

I ran it in java 11 and 17 and the output in both versions is:

```
Test 1: Case 2
Test 2: Case 2
Test 3: Case 2
Test 4: Case 2
```

I would have expected that only test 1 and 5 actually compile, but they all compile and it seems that everything after the actual label is just ignored.

I doubt this is an oversight, so what am I missing?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Where in your code you have something like this:

```
case A:BARFOO:
```

`BARFOO:` isn't a switch case. It's nothing to do with the switch mechanics. It's just a label. You're allowed to label any statement, but it's not always useful. It's typically used for loops: e.g.

```
outerloop:
while (true) {
    while (true) {
        break outerloop;
    }
}
```

---

If you actually wanted to group together multiple cases, you could write it like:

```
case A: case B:
    ...
    break;
```

And as Jesper mentions in the comments, more recent versions of Java also support a [switch expression](https://openjdk.java.net/jeps/361), under which the syntax is:

```
case A, B -> ...
```

Comment: And if you use the [new `switch` syntax](https://openjdk.java.net/jeps/361) you could write `case A, B -> ...`

Comment: Thanks for the additional info, I knew about the `case A: case B: ` syntax, but not about the new way with commas.